# When exactly does Athena require rescanning partitions with MSCK REPAIR TABLE?

Tags: amazon-athena

It is not clear from the documentation, whether you need to run `MSCK REPAIR TABLE` every time new data is added to a partition, or only when a whole new partition value shows up in the data (i.e. upon insertion of a new "folder" in S3 by creating an object in a certain path [I know, there are no true folders in S3]).

Does anybody know how it's supposed to work?

Comment: I have suggested a change to the docs to clarify some of this, but it's been almost two months and it hasn't been merged yet: https://github.com/awsdocs/amazon-athena-user-guide/pull/31

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Athena relies on "Hive table layout", just uses Glue metastore for that.
In Glue, you registers *partitions*, not individual *files*.

If you create a new partition folder, you need to register it (and this is what `MSCK REPAIR TABLE` does, among other things).

If you just add new files, you don't need to do anything.

Note: `MSCK REPAIR TABLE` is not necessarily the faster way to discover new partitions. Presto 319 comes with builtin [Hive connector procedure: `sync_partition_metadata`](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/connector/hive.html#procedures) that can be used for this purpose. Of course, this is available when using Presto directly. It's not available in Athena (even though it is based on Presto).